# What is the matrix of $e^{p(B)}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given $n \times n $ matrix B define $e^B$  by $$e^B= \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{B^j}{j !} $$ Let p be the characteristic polynomial of B. Then the matrix $e^{p(B)}$ is???

Comment: What do you know about the characteristic polynomial of a matrix, applied to that matrix? (You're looking for the Cayley–Hamilton theorem.)

Comment: What does $B^j$ mean here ?

Comment: @user230452 The notation is fairly standard

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I don't have much experience with matrices. So, I asked.

Comment: @user230452:   It is a fair question.  $B^j$ is the matrix $B$ raised to the $j$th power.  For positive integer $j \ge 1$ it is clear what this means.  For $j=0$ it is a matter of convention in the context of power series that $B^0=I$ the identity matrix.

Comment: @hardmath But, it isn't a number ? I thought it meant the determinant of $B$ so you can sum up numbers. I guess you're summing up matrices here.

Comment: @user230452:  Not a "number" unless $B$ is $1\times 1$.  The matrix exponential $e^B$ maps square matrices to square matrices of the same size (number of rows = number of columns).

Comment: @hardmath I see. So, what does it mean for an exponential characteristic polynomial ? Is $e^AB = e^Ae^B$?

Comment: @user230452:  If you have a new Question to ask, it would be better to post it rather than to extend the Comments.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comments: look up the Cayley Hamilton theorem. There isn't anything worth adding to that.

Answer (score 1):

I try to solve.
$e^B$ , It gives $e^B= \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{B^j}{j !}$

$e^B= \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{B^j}{j !}=I + \frac{B^1}{ 1!}+\frac{B^2+}{ 2!}+\frac{B^3}{ 3!}+\dots $

Now p is characteristic polynomial of B $\implies $ $p(B)=0$ By cayleyHamilton theorem.
Now calculate $e^{p(B)}$ .

$e^{p(B)}=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{p(B)^j}{j !}=I + \frac{p(B)^1}{ 1!}+\frac{p(B)^2+}{ 2!}+\frac{p(B)^3}{ 3!}+\dots $

$e^{p(B)}=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{p(B)^j}{j !}=I + 0+0+0+\dots $

$e^{p(B)}=I_{n \times n} $

Comment: That's exactly the right idea.

Answer (score -1):

Determinant of characteristic matrix in terms of λ is known as charecteristic polynomial.

If p be the charecteristic polynomial then you can use this relation to solve it

e^B= a$1$+a$2$I  where I be the identity matrix
e^p=a$1$+a$2$I
Form 2 equation by use of 2nd equation .by putting 2 values of p